# Unable to remove hash tags from domain name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a one page site with five anchor links in it. When I open the site, the address bar displays `domain.com/#numberofpage`

I could not find a solution to remove the hash tags display, maybe I am using incorrect keywords to find this.

Could you please help to solve this?

Comment: Do you have hashes in the href on your links by any chance?

Comment: To stop the fragments being shown in the URL on click of the link, use `event.preventDefault()` within the click handler.

Comment: Yes I have hashes in the hrefs. The things I don't want to remove only hash tags but the the whole link name as well. To display the domain name only. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = window.location.href;
$('#change').on('click', function() {
 var arr = url.split('?');
 arr.pop();
 window.location.href = arr[0];
});
```

But that would also go to to `domain.com` if you don't the page to actually go anywhere.

Therefore You will have to add hash # if you want to prevent page from reloading.

The css-tricks.com has an excellent screencast on that, have a look at: [Best Practices with Dynamic Content](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/85-best-practices-dynamic-content/)